# Some statements are printed in console whenever i interact with my flutter app. How to stop it?

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I recently upgraded to flutter 1.20 since then whenever i run my app there are some statements that are printed in console , it did not happen before upgrading.Is there any way to stop it.

[image: This gets printed along with many other statements when i interact with my app]